# EasyRandom collection size bug?

Tags: java, junit

I'm using easy random (4.1.0, but even tried the latest ones).

So before each test, I'm running this:

```
easyRandom = new EasyRandom(new EasyRandomParameters().collectionSizeRange(1, 2));
```

Then in my tests I'm generating an object which contains an inner object which also contains a List of SomeObject

```
MyObj obj = easyRandom.nextObject(MyObj.class);
```

It works fine. It generates the object and even populates the inner collection with 1-2 elements.
One colleague of mine had a problem where the inner collection was generated with 0 elements.
Thought it was something from his setup. But now, our pipelines are ending in build failure because of the exact same problem. That collection is generated with 0 elements and the tests are failing, even though it works locally.

Has anyone met this weird bug?

Comment: What type is the collection with a size of zero?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Even if that code works for you locally, it would **really** help if we saw the code that failed in your build pipelines. My wild guess woud be something related to unit test execution being different in your build vs. your local test runs (did you try running the tests locally via your build script?).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, its a list of a custom object.
JoachimSauer I really think it's a bug in the library, since it's not failing just on the build, it also fails locally when a colleague of mine tries

Comment: @UnguruBulan: possible. But without a reproducible example you won't get far. Reduce the code to the minimum possible that still fails at your collegues computer. Remove unnecessary tests, replace your custom classes with simple dummies, do everything possible to reduce the code until you've got a minimal, reproducible example. With that we can continue the hunt, but with just your description above, it's really anyone's guess.

Comment: I found the problem. Will post the solution later on. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

This was my case:

By default, if your class has some fields already initialized, EasyRandom skips them.

This is the case also for initialization at declaration such as `List<YourClass> yourList = new ArrayList<>()`. Even if the collection itself is empty, EasyRandom skips such field.

You can use `overrideDefaultInitialization(true)` to change this behavior

```
 new EasyRandomParameters()
        .collectionSizeRange(1, 2)
        .overrideDefaultInitialization(true)
```